# Unresolved reference:DetailActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working through an example of changing an image in Android Studio, but cannot work out what is the problem with Unresolved Reference for DetailActivity. I am working thought this example and cannot see what is the problem or what is missing.

```
  package com.example.sandpit8

  import android.content.Intent
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.telecom.Call
  import android.util.Log

  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*

  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    imageButton.setOnClickListener{viewMonsterImage(R.drawable.button)}
}

private fun viewMonsterImage(imageButton: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity)
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    startActivity(intent)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a spelling mistake with the DetailActivity, all working now

Answer (score 1):

Try create intent in the following way:

```
val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
```

And, of course, import the `DetailsActivity` if it's situated in another package

Comment: Many thanks, how do I import the DetailsActivity, as it's still reference unresolved activity?

Comment: What is full source code of file with the `DetailsActivity`?

Comment: I don't have any code, does that mean I need to create the file? Looking at the example it's a ready made activity, or is that not the case and it's a file I have to create?

Comment: What example do you use? And how did you define `DetailsAcivity` in your own project?

Comment: The example is from Lynda.com, I did not see the Activity been added I thought this was an internal function (not sure if that is the correct name). I have to watch the video again, but he types in the name and it auto inserts the DetailsActivity. May be he added it some where else?

Comment: Android has no `DetailsActivity`, you should create it yourself.

Comment: Okay, may be have to look at a different example of ImageButton presses and how to change the picture. Something so simple, is difficult to get my brain around.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
private fun viewMonsterImage(imageButton: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity)
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

to this

```
private fun viewMonsterImage(imageButton: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```